# Relating text fields to check boxes in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

This program requires the user to login and request a database to access.  The program then gets a connection object, searches through the database storing the column names into a vector for later use.  The problem comes with implementing text fields to allow the user to search for specific values within the database.

I can get the check boxes and text fields to appear using a gridlayout and add them to a panel.  How do I relate the text fields to their appropriate check box?

I've tried adding them to a vector, but then they can't also be added to the panel as well.  I've searched for a way to name the text fields as the loop cycles through the column names, but it seems impossible to do without having them declared ahead of time.  This can't be done either, as it's impossible to determine the attributes that the user will request.

I just need to be able to know the names of the text fields so I can test to see if the user entered information and perform the necessary logic.  Let me know if you have to see the rest of the code to give an answer, but hopefully you get the general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Picture of UI:

[image: Picture of UI:]

```
 try {
        ResultSet r2 = con.getMetaData().getColumns("", "", rb.getText(), "");  
        colNames1 = new Vector<String>();  
        columns1 = new Vector<JCheckBox>();  
        while (r2.next()) {  
            colNames1.add(r2.getString(4));  
            JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox(r2.getString(4));  
            JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);  
            columns1.add(cb);  
            p3.add(cb);  
            p3.add(tf);  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: How are you adding them to the vector and to the panel? Why can't the same object be added to both? (In other words, what are you trying, and what happens that you don't like?)

Comment: This block of code is for the second set of check boxes, hence the text fields in the code and next to the boxes in the image.  I need a way to be able to reference the text fields so as to perform getText() methods on them.  I need a way to name them using the column names (r2.getString(4)) so I can for example use sname.getText() to see what the user entered.  But it seems it's only possible to use a single name (I chose tf in this case) as opposed to naming them after each column every time it goes through the loop.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also I'm not sure why it lets me add the check box to the vector AND the panel, yet won't let me do so for the text fields.

Comment: If you're trying to add the JTextField to either of the vectors you've defined, it's because the JTextField is neither a String nor a JCheckBox.

Comment: Can you post a copy of the code you're using to add the JTextField to a collection and the panel? It still isn't clear what's happening when you say that it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Vector is an old class that shouldn't be used for years. Use ArrayList instead.

Second, if you want to associate an obect with another object, then use a Map:

```
Map<String, JTextField> textFieldsByColumnName = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
for (...) {
    String columnName = ...;
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    map.put(columnName, tf);
}
```

Then, when you want the textfield associated with a given column name, just use

```
JTextField tf = textFieldsByColumnName.get(columnName);
```

Learn about collections in the [collection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). This is something that any Java programmer must know.

Comment: I think you understand the problem, but I want the text field immediately associated with the column name.  Can I put the column name into the map, associate the text field with the name, and then put the text field into the map?

The order you have suggests that you later create an entire new text field floating around not in the panel and associate it with the column name, rendering a getText() call useless.

Comment: That's what the map does: map.put(columnName, tf) associates the textfield referenced by `tf` with the column name referenced by `columnName`. I don't see where I suggest that I later create a new text field floating around.

Comment: So by later creating a new `JTextField tf`, is it creating a clone of the one associated with `columnName` so you can access the text the user input into the field?

Comment: No. I'm not creating a new JTextField, and the code doesn't create any clone. It's just getting a textfield from the map. Just like when you do `JTextField tf = vector.get(0)`: you get a textfield stored in the first position of the vector. Just like when you put something in a labeled box, and later find the box thanks to its label, open it, and get back the object your previously stored.

Comment: Thanks for your help, somehow got the rest of it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of component composition, you could extend JPanel with a class that contains both a check box and the text field. This can be used to build custom components that provide new behaviors, without having to write your own input components from scratch.

```
class CheckableTextField extends JPanel {
    JTextField textField;
    JCheckBox checkBox;

    public CheckableTextField(String label) {
        this.checkBox = new JCheckBox(label);
        this.textField = new JTextField(10);

        this.add(this.checkBox);
        this.add(this.textField);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.textField.getText();
    }

    public isSelected() {
        return this.checkBox.isSelected();
    }
}
```

You could then use the CheckableTextField in place of the individual JTextField and JCheckBox objects. It would behave as though Java came with a component that did exactly what you want. You could further customize the custom component in a number of ways, such as by changing the layout within the constructor.

It's fairly common to use composition to build your own components using object-oriented frameworks like Swing (for GUI apps) or JSF (for web applications).

Answer (score 0):

It's best to write a custom component, just as stated by GaragantuChet. This also makes layout and a custom focus traversal strategy easier. I'd also recommend having a look at miglayout, which makes creating more complex and dynamic screens easier.

http://www.miglayout.com/

Once this is done, it's ready to store the custom components in a map, with the column names as key.